# rewrite with htaccess (i tried to use solutions from other topics)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I use wordpress 3.4.2.
I tried to change url with htaccess, but i have next problem:
RewriteRule ^order/([0-9])/$ index.php?pagename=order&type=$1 - works!
RewriteRule ^order/([a-z])/$ index.php?pagename=order&type=$1 - "not found" or redirects on other page(example)!

example:
if I enter www.mywebsite.com/order/a/, it'll be redirecting at page www.mywebsite.com/about/ 
(if it exists or "not found").

P.S. I'm a newcomer, so don't be angry.

P.S. Solved.

Comment: What happens when you go to index.php?pagename=order&type=x ?

Comment: What is the desired result of going to /a/, do they see the same content as /about/, does the url change?

Comment: /a/ - value, which i need get from a page www.bb.com/order/ .

Comment: i have another way to solve a problem. Thanks to everybody for effort.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that you are only matching a single digit or single lowercase letter?

This would match more than one digit/letter.

```
RewriteRule ^order/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?pagename=order&type=$1
RewriteRule ^order/([a-z]+)/$ index.php?pagename=order&type=$1
```

This isn't actually redirecting though. To the user the URL they are visiting will not change. This is just rewriting the url on the server so that users have prettier URLs.

If you actually want to redirect you would have to do:

```
Redirect 301 /a/ http://mywebsite.com/about/
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I use next urls to check htaccess: http://www.mywebsite.com/order/1/ and http://www.mywebsite.com/order/a/

Comment: So you are saying when you use /1/ it rewrites correctly but /a/ shows a not found message?

Comment: sory for "redirect". I want to make other query if pattern'll match.